# How to share a gif image to Wechat?

Tags: android, image, gif, wechat

I am developing an app which can share gif image to Wechat and QQ, but I have a problem when sharing a gif image to Wechat.

I can use `WXImageObject` to share a local gif image to Wechat, but it doesn't display on Chatroom of Wechat. And I clicked the gif image, it can be shown as a image but not a gif image. And I can't share a network image to Wechat.

I have tried `WXWebpageObject` and `WXEmojiObject`, but I falied.
Is there anyone know how to share a gif image to Wechat?

Comment: First you should make sure that if WeChat APIs support GIF to share.

Comment: @Mycroft, Maybe it would be better to share some code so we can help or provide a solution you were able to come with so others can benefit from it.

Comment: @Mycroft wong use this :      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007067/ios-share-gif-animated-image-not-working/44041180#44041180